# Ionic error Un-handled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function Promise.then is not a function in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3

I have created app in ionic 3 but i got error after ionic serve got above error i have google it and try to solve error via different post but problem is not resolve?

**Setps for resproduce** :-

npm i @ngx-translate/core@9.1.1

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at new ApplicationRef (vendor.js:15312)
at _createClass (vendor.js:18294)
at _createProviderInstance (vendor.js:18256)
at initNgModule (vendor.js:18189)
at new NgModuleRef_ (vendor.js:18916)
at Object.createNgModuleRef (vendor.js:18905)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (vendor.js:21464)
at vendor.js:15117
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:14655) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at new ApplicationRef (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:15312:64)
at _createClass (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:18294:20)
at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:18256:26)
at initNgModule (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:18189:32)
at new NgModuleRef_ (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:18916:9)
at Object.createNgModuleRef (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:18905:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:21464:25)
at http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:15117:43
at t.invoke (http://localhost:5000/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:5000/build/vendor.js:14655:33)
```

Comment: It seems that something in one of your promises is not set up correctly. Can you input some code for that, or perhaps where you think it might be coming from?

Comment: Sir i don't what are u saying, this error is occur after ionic serve?